# MQTT - Is QOS level 2 better for larger payloads?

Tags: mqtt

QOS 1 may resend the messages multiple times I believe.

For large payloads, is QOS 2 better as it ensures payload only sent once?

There is extra back and forth for QOS 2 but I assume that is sending a checksum of the payload and not the payload itself.

Therefore my thinking is that the little bit of extra network comms is better than risking the large payload being sent multiple times

Comment: There is no chance of a message being sent twice with QOS0. QOS0 -> maybe once, QOS1 -> at least once, QOS2 -> only once

Answer (score 2):

The difference between QOS1 and QOS2 is more about ensuring a message is only **processed** once by the receiver. Consider the packets sent at each level:

```
QOS1 - PUBLISH -> PUBACK
QOS2 - PUBLISH -> PUBREC -> PUBREL -> PUBCOMP
```

In either case, if the connection with the broker is lost before the initial acknowledgment (`PUBACK`/`PUBREC`) is received, then the full message (including payload) needs to be resent. So operating at `QOS2` does not guarantee that the message will not be transmitted across the network link multiple times.

At `QOS1` once the `PUBACK` is sent the `MessageID` is available for reuse; as such if a message with that ID is received you cannot reliably tell if it's a duplicate (the `DUP` flag provides a hint but not the full solution).

When operating at `QOS2` you wait until a `PUBREL` is received before forgetting about the `MessageID`. The `PUBREL` basically says "I have received your `PUBREC` and will not resend that message); this means you can provide guarantees that the message will only be processed once.

Given that MQTT runs over TCP (which provides it's own guarantees) `QOS2` will generate more network traffic than `QOS1` (assuming identical message contents and link conditions).

However it is possible that additional traffic will be generated if the broker receives duplicate `QOS1` messages because it will then pass these onto any subscribers (whereas at `QOS2` the broker will detect the duplication and only send one copy). This means that the answer is going to depend upon your situation (what network links the message crosses, number of subscribers, whether it's important to the receiver that its unique, whether subscribers can detect duplicates another way etc).

*Note that the above assumes that messages will **only** be resent when the connection drops; this is required by the MQTTv5 spec. MQTTv3 allows messages to be resent at other times but I believe that most brokers now follow the v5 standard on this.*